# Android/iOS setting page printing settings

Tags: javascript, android, ios, pdf, printing

I am looking for setting page printings in android or iOS. 
What for?
I would like to print PDFs from my phone. There are some apps which make this possible. BUT there is no possibility to print multiple PDF pages/ or slides one page. For example like it is possible in every PDF Reader on the PC or MAC - 4 pages on one real page.

Is there an Applikation which does this or are there some code lines which make this possible? Maybe javascript?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. If you are writing a PDF viewer, and you are having difficulty composing a print job that implements 4-up printing, please provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you have tried and explaining the details of what is not working.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice.
I am writing the application with:
[link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Custom_Document_Printing_Tutorial)
this tutorial. I just wanted to know if it is possible in general to set printer settings. I ve  never done it before. And google was not helpful.(maye it is becaus I dont know what Iam looking for)

Comment: No, you cannot set printer settings on Android. You provide the `PrintAttributes` to `print()` suggesting what you want; the user might override some of these as part of printing.